# Merge two dataframes according to their shared values

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, subset

I have two data frames. The first one is like this:

```
df1<-read.table(text="   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
               1   a   a   1.5147654   1.5147654   1.5147654
               2   a   c   1.97638457  1.97638457  1.97638457
               3   c   d   1.55151792  -2.38160971 1.55151792
               4   a   b   2.25182522  2.25182522  -1.3523473
               5   b   d   1.85349445  1.85349445  1.85349445
               ",
               header=TRUE)
```

And the second one is like below:

```
df2<-read.table(text="   V1  V2  V3
                   1    a   b   1
                   2    c   a   1.5
                   3    d   b   3.5
                   4    d   c   5.1
                   ",
                   header=TRUE)
```

I want to merge them in such a way that my final result would be like that:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
a   b   1   2.25182522  2.25182522  -1.3523473
c   a   1.5 1.97638457  1.97638457  1.97638457
d   b   3.5 1.85349445  1.85349445  1.85349445
d   c   5.1 1.55151792  -2.38160971 1.55151792
```

I mean that if the values of two first columns of df2 be in the first two columns of df1, then I would like to merge them to have the above result. Any idea about it?

Comment: Just to clarify : You want to merge them based on columns `A` and `B` but the order does not matter ?

Comment: I want to merge them according to V1 and V2 columns. By order if you mean for example a and be or b and a ii does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

Make odered *key* column then merge:

```
df1$key <- apply(df1[1:2], 1, function(i) toString(sort(i)))
df2$key <- apply(df2[1:2], 1, function(i) toString(sort(i)))

merge(df2, df1, by = "key")
#    key V1.x V2.x V3.x V1.y V2.y     V3.y        V4        V5
# 1 a, b    a    b  1.0    a    b 2.251825  2.251825 -1.352347
# 2 a, c    c    a  1.5    a    c 1.976385  1.976385  1.976385
# 3 b, d    d    b  3.5    b    d 1.853494  1.853494  1.853494
# 4 c, d    d    c  5.1    c    d 1.551518 -2.381610  1.551518
```